# condition for one-form to be exact differential

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, differential

Simple question I suppose:

Having a (smooth) one-form 
$$\omega=\omega_i dx^i\in \Lambda(M)$$

Is there a test to find out if $\omega$ is exact differential? 
Or more precisely that there exists a function $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$, s.t $\omega=df$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A necessary condition is that $d\omega = 0$, that is, the form must be closed, but there is no general method to determine if $\omega$ is exact, unless $M$ is an open ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$, for in that case *every* closed form is exact, a result known as [Poincaré  Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms#Poincar%C3%A9_lemma).

**Additional Information**

The article in Wikipedia about [differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) can help you understanding the basics about differential forms. A search in this site would be very helpful as well. Now I would limit myself to 1-forms, like the form $\omega$. As I have said in a comment, the exterior derivative of $\omega$ is 
$$
d\omega = \frac{\partial \omega_i}{\partial x^j}dx^j\wedge dx^i.
$$
The wedge product between 1-forms is antisymmetric (for general forms it is *skew commutative*, see the Wikipedia article), that is, 
$$
dx^i\wedge dx^j = dx^i\otimes dx^j - dx^j\otimes dx^i.
$$
Then the product $dx\wedge dx$ is zero. The skew commutativity property is essential to show that any *exact* form is a *closed* form. For example, let us suppose that $\omega = df$ for some function $f$ and, for the sake of simplicity, that we are dealing with $\mathbb{R}^2$ with coordinates $x$ and $y$. Then
$$
d\omega = d(df)=d(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy)= 
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}dy\wedge dx + 
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}dx\wedge dy, 
$$
where the terms containing $dx\wedge dx$ and $dy\wedge dy$ were omitted. By the equality of mixed partial derivatives and the fact that $dx\wedge dy = -dy\wedge dx$, you can conclude that $d\omega=d(df)=0$.

Comment: It is enough that $M$ be *simply connected*.

Comment: Or, more precisely, that $M$ have $H^1(M,\Bbb R) = 0$.

Comment: How do you calculate $d\omega$? Is it a (0,2) tensor ?

Comment: $d\omega = \frac{\partial\omega_i}{\partial x^j}dx^j\wedge dx^i$ and yes, it is a $(0,2)$ tensor.

Comment: I'm so sorry for being a pain in the a###, but... I don't get what is $\wedge$. I thought that is pretty the same as to say " a symmetric tensor $dx^i \otimes dx^j$". Apparently I was wrong. Let $M=\mathbb{R}^2$ with cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$ and  $f=\frac{x^2}{2}$. Now $\omega=df= x dx$ and $d\omega=1 dx\wedge dx \neq 0$